# Prove that integral is a Gaussian random variable, compute its mean and variance

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have to prove that $X_t=\int_0^t W_s ds$ is a Gaussian random variable. I need also to compute it's mean and variance.

**My attempt:**

Let $W_t$ be a simple adapted process
$$W_t=\xi_0\mathbf{1}_0(t)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \xi_i \mathbf{1}_{(t_i,t_{i+1}]}(t)$$
where $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=T$ and $\xi_i$ are measurable with respect to $F_{t_i}$ and $E[\xi_i^2]<\infty$

Then the integral of this process with respect to time is given by
$$\int_0^T W_sds=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \xi_i (t_{i+1}-t_i)$$
If I can prove that this integral is Gaussian, I will prove that $X_t$ is Gaussian, since a limit of Gaussian processes is Gaussian. Any help?

Comment: You wrote Itō integral in the title but wrote out $\int_0^t W_s ds$, which denotes the [integrated Wiener process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Integrated_Brownian_motion). Don't you mean the Riemann integral of the Wiener process?

Comment: Yes, I mean the Riemann integral. My mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition of a Riemann integral, we have that the Riemann sum for a partition $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_N=T$ is
$$
S_N = \sum_{i=1}^N W(t_i)(t_i - t_{i-1}),
$$
Now, we have that $W(t_i) = \sum_{k=1}^i[W(t_k) - W(t_{k-1})]$, so 
$$
S_N = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^i[W(t_k) - W(t_{k-1})](t_i - t_{i-1}).
$$
$$
S_N = \sum_{i=1}^N[W(t_i) - W(t_{i-1})](T - t_{i-1}).
$$
Since the increments of the Wiener process are independent and Gaussian with variance equal to the time increment, we have that
$$
E[S_N^2] = \sum_{i=1}^N[t_i - t_{i-1}](T - t_{i-1})^2.
$$
The expression above is a Riemann sum too, so when the mesh of the partition vanishes and $N\to\infty$, we have that
$$
E\left[\left(\int_0^T W(t)\,dt\right)^2\right] = \int_0^T (T-t)^2\,dt = \frac{T^3}{3}
$$

Gaussian random variables form a linear subspace of $L_2$, since Gaussianity is closed with respect to addition and multiplication by scalar, i.e., if X and Y are Gaussian random variables then
$$
Z = aX + bY
$$
is also a Gaussian random variable. A subspace of a Hilbert space is also a Hilbert space, so it is complete. You can then use [dominated convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Dominated_convergence_in_Lp-spaces_.28corollary.29) to show that $S_N$ converges in $L_2$ (mean square convergence), so that its limit is also Gaussian. Taking the expected value of $S_N$ it is also easy to see that the integral is zero-mean.

Comment: Note that the expression I got for the variance is the same as [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Integrated_Brownian_motion), so I believe it is correct.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian, is it true that $aX+bY$ is also Gaussian? I think $X,Y$ have to be independent for this to be true.

Comment: As $W_s$ is a Gaussian process, all finite linear combinations are Gaussian. The integral in question is a Riemann integral due to continuity of $W_s$ and so $\sum_i W_{t_i} (t_{i+1}-t_i) \to \int_0^t W_s ds$ a.s. Now, the almost sure limit of Gaussian random variables is Gaussain and hence the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way of showing this result is to use the (stochastic)-integration by part formula :

$\int_0^tW_sds= W_t-W_0 - \int_0^tsdWs$ ( no quadratic covariation term has s has 0 quadratic variation)

The first term is normal and independent from the stochastic integral which is a Wiener integral. As Wiener integrals are normal random variables, we have written  $\int_0^tW_sds$ as the sum of 2 independent normal variables showing that it is itself a normal random variable (BTW mean and variance are easy to get using Itô's isometry and martingale property of stochastic integrals).

Best regards

Comment: Another alternative way to prove it is using linear systems theory and convolution, see http://wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=39502

Comment: @Dimas it appears your link is dead.