# Statistical property of the difference between wiener process and the integral of the wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

It is known that Wiener increments are stationary and normally distributed:

$$
W_{s}-W_{t} \sim N(0,s-t)
$$

Is the difference between a Wiener process and its integral also normally distributed? Namely, is

$$
W_{s}-\int_{0}^{s}W_{t}dt
$$

normally distributed ($t<s$)? If so, how do I show it? And what are its statistical properties(mean, variance)?

**Edit: Here is my attempt**

Based on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664472/prove-that-integral-is-a-gaussian-random-variable-compute-its-mean-and-variance), it seems that if

$$
X_{s}=\int_{0}^{s}W_tdt
$$

then $X_{s} \sim N(0,\frac{s^{3}}{3})$. Since [the sum of two independent random variables is simply the sum of their means and variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables), I have that

$$
W_s - X_s \sim N\left(0,s+\frac{s^{3}}{3}\right).
$$

Is this correct? I'm assuming $W_s$ and $X_s$ are independent.

Comment: is $s>T$?.......

Comment: @NN2 Thank you for pointing out my typo. I have updated the question based on your feedback

Comment: Why $W_s$ and $X_s$ would be independent? (they're not)

Comment: PS: According to the rules on Stack Exchange, you should go back to your previous questions and accept the answers that answered your questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected value of average of Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250526/expected-value-of-average-of-brownian-motion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We transform the integral $\int_0^sW_tdt$
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^sW_tdt &= \int_0^s\left(\int_0^t dW_u  \right)dt  \\
&= \iint_{0\le u \le t \le s} dW_u \cdot dt  \\
&= \iint_{0\le u \le t \le s}  dt \cdot  dW_u \\
 &= \int_0^s\left(\int_u^s dt  \right)dW_u  \\
&= \int_0^s(s-u)dW_u  \\
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{W_s - \int_0^sW_tdt} &=\int_0^sdW_u - \int_0^s(s-u)dW_u \\
&=\color{red}{\int_0^s (1-s+u) dW_u} \\
\end{align}$$

We deduce easily that

$$W_s - \int_0^sW_tdt \sim\mathcal{N} \left(0, \int_0^s(1-s+u)^2du  \right) = \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left(0, s-s^2 +\frac{s^3}{3}  \right)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate more on the last step. Specifically, how did you "deduce easily" the variance of the quantity? Can you show the steps there?

Comment: @kowalski It can be deduced easily from the property :Itô isometry  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry  .  In fact, for $X_t$ deterministic, the Ito integral follows normal distribution with mean of $0$ and variance computed from the Ito isometry property.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n\in\mathbb N^*$, $W_s-\frac{s}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nW_{ks/n}$ is gaussian, so its almost sure limit $W_s-\int_0^sW_t\,dt$ is gaussian.

Then the mean is
$$
\mathbb E[W_s]-\int_0^s\mathbb E[W_t]\,dt=0,
$$
and the variance is
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\left(W_s-\int_0^sW_t\,dt\right)^2\right]&=\mathbb E[W_s^2]-2\int_0^s\mathbb E[W_sW_t]\,dt+\int_0^s\int_0^{s'}\mathbb E[W_tW_{t'}]\,dt\,dt'\\
&=s-s^2+\frac{s^3}{3}.
\end{align}$$